# How to define generic type for store with specific action in Pinia?

Tags: typescript, pinia

I would like to have strictly typed stores that match specific pattern. For all stores, I require that they have specific action.

```
function doSomethingWithStore (useStore: StoreWithRequiredAction) {
  const store = useStore()
  const param = {}
  store.requiredAction(param)
}

const okStore = defineStore('id', {
   state: ...,
   getters: ...,
   actions: {
      requiredAction (param: object) {

      },
      // other actions
   }
})

const notOkStore = defineStore('id2', {
   state: ...,
   getters: ...,
   actions: {
      // required action missing
   }
})

// should be ok
doSomethingWithStore(okStore)
// type check should fail since store is missing the action 
doSomethingWihtStore(notOkStore)
```

Any ideas how `StoreWithRequiredAction` type would look like?

Comment: erm , `() => { requiredAction(param: object): void }` ?